# How to pass vector to pointer array winapi?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I want to stop using manual allocated memory to work with all winapi. for testing i  try to change my code. but i get

> no suitable conversion from vector DWORD to DWORD * exists.

```
std::vector<DWORD> aProcesses;
DWORD cbNeeded;
if (!EnumProcesses(aProcesses, aProcesses.capacity(), &cbNeeded))
{
    return 1;
}
for (auto& p : aProcesses)
{
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
}
```

Manual Allocated memory below

```
    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
unsigned int i;
if (!EnumProcesses(aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded))
{
    return 1;
}


// Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.

cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

// Print the name and process identifier for each process.

for (i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++)
{
    if (aProcesses[i] != 0)
    {
        std::cout << aProcesses[i] << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: instead of aProcesses` use `aProcesses.data()` or alternately `&aProcesses[0]` see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data

Comment: Note that you need to call `resize()` on the vector yourself before passing a pointer to the data buffer to an API function, since Windows doesn't know anything about c++.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the code you anticipate replacing to provide more specific advice.

Comment: @doug i include manual allocate memory ways

Comment: Just declare your vector like so: `std::vector<DWORD> aProcesses(1024);` and use `aProcesses.data()` which is a pointer to the first vector element.

Comment: @doug is not manually allocated memory. cause i need to know the max possible the value of array?

Comment: I see from your code that you also need to adjust for the bytes in a DWORD. I'm not familiar with the API you are calling but declaring a regular array of size 1024 and a vector of the same size are similar except that the vector allocates on the heap. They both automatically release memory when going out of scope. I presume they aren't being declared in global space but in a function. I had assumed you were allocating with a new in the code you were replacing.

Comment: BTW, you probably should use `.size()` instead of `.capacity()`.

Answer (score 0):

A `vector` isn't a pointer to `DWORD`; however, this `vector` happens to contain one so you can

```
if (!EnumProcesses(aProcesses.data(), aProcesses.capacity(), &cbNeeded))
```

if your compiler is compiling for the C++11 Standard revision or more recent or

```
if (!EnumProcesses(&aProcesses[0], aProcesses.capacity(), &cbNeeded))
```

if it is not.

## But that just gets things compiling

There are logic problems yet to be dealt with.

```
const int MAX_PROCESSES = 1024; // very few Windows systems will exceed 1024 processes

std::vector<DWORD> aProcesses(MAX_PROCESSES); // allocate space
DWORD cbNeeded;
if (!EnumProcesses(aProcesses.data(), 
                   aProcesses.capacity() * sizeof(DWORD), // size in bytes, not elements  
                   &cbNeeded))
{
    return 1;
}
//for (auto& p : aProcesses) Not all processes may have been filled. The unused portions 
//are zeroed, so this is safe, but wasteful
for (int i = 0; i < cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD); ++i)
{
    std::cout << aProcesses[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: is not MAX_NUM_DWORDS macro manually allocated memory? i should knows max possible the value?

Comment: @Dwersonbusch No, that was a stub. There is pretty much no way to know how many processes are running, but this rarely gets above a few hundred on all but the busiest of servers. Will update question.

Comment: EnumProcesses api it just example. i knows if max processes will not run above 1k. but there's other winapi it will return above 1k value.

Comment: Why do you say that `&aProcesses[0]` isn't legal? `aProcesses[0]` returns a reference, `T&`, and taking the address of a reference is just a pointer to the referenced object. A DWORD in this case.

Comment: @doug I can't imagine how you could do `vector` and the  `[]` overload so that `&vec[0]` won't work, but it's not guaranteed. It's only an issue with C++ 98 and 03, so I did some old school standard diving and in 2005 drafts the wording looks like *obeys the identity &v[n] == &v[0] + n for all 0 <= n < v.size().* Looks pretty conclusive that it ought to work and I'm gonna have to stop. It's too damn late and I work in the morning. And I'm having trouble typing work. Always a bad sign.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if (!EnumProcesses(aProcesses, aProcesses.capacity(), &cbNeeded))
> ```

won't work well. First thing is, you need to pass `aProcesses.data()` as the first parameter and the number of *bytes* `aProcess` can hold as the 2nd: `aProcesses.size() * sizeof(DOWD)`.

If `cbNeeded` >= `aProcess.size() * sizeof(DWORD)` after the call, you have to resize the `vector` to `cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD)` and call `EnumProcesses()` again to make sure you got all processes.

Comment: if like that. is it call EnumProcesses twice. it make execution slow?

Comment: You have no other choice if you don't pass an array that is big enough the first time you call `EnumProcesses()`.